# page number jumps in log file

Tags: macros, page-numbering

I compiled a document back in 2016 (with TeXLive 2016) and noticed the following strange situation. The page number jumps 76 to 89, when including the next file with a new chapter. (the file starts with `\chapter` macro).
Which macro is able to change the page number at this level?

```
[56] [57]
File: Figuras/fig173.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)
 <use  "Figuras/fig173.pdf" > [58] [59] [60] [61] [62] [63] [64] [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [73] [74]) [75]
\openout2 = `capitulo2.aux'.

 (./capitulo2.tex [76




]
Capítulo 2.

Overfull \hbox (0.71048pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
\EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/12 tria Analítica, veremos agora como a eficiência desses métodos cresce ainda
 []

[89]
File: Figuras/fig181.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)
 <use  "Figuras/fig181.pdf" > [90]
File: Figuras/fig182.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)
 <use  "Figuras/fig182.pdf" > [91]
Fil
```

Comment: Well you only have to do `\setcounter{page}{123}` and it will jump.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any explicit `\setcounter`, neither in the tex files, not the class or styles that I have created.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the cause - without code one can't say anything definite - but it shows that it is easy to change this number. No magic needed.

Comment: Barbara thinks that the numbers are there but on the far right of the log

Comment: I know it is impossible to get the thing without code, but o have some classes and styles that I can't make public. Definitely I must be something in the redefinition of \chapter, but it was done with titlesec package.I scrolled to the right but there is nothing.

Comment: I find also strange the blank lines in some page numbers.

Comment: If you use `\includeonly` the page number will skip over the range for skipped files. Blanks within the page number brackets are due to log output while shipping out a page.

Comment: Finaly,  I found several `\setcounter{page}` buried in the tex files. There where quite hidden. Thank for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Macros that can alter the page number in the log files are.

- `\setcounter{page}{number}`. Used to change the page number (for
  example, after `\mainmatter`
- When skipping files that are `\include`
  using `\includeonly`